# Spring Data JPA: Many-To-Many mapping between two tables when one of the table is itself a Join Table for another Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Please see my [entity-relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWC4g.jpg) to understand the data setup.

***DB Scripts:***

```
CREATE TABLE manager
(
    id           NUMBER (12, 0) NOT NULL,
    code         VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    first_name   VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    last_name    VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT manager_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT manager_uk1 UNIQUE (code)
);

CREATE TABLE employee
(
    id           NUMBER (12, 0) NOT NULL,
    code         VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    first_name   VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    last_name    VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT employee_uk1 UNIQUE (code)
);

CREATE TABLE manager_employee
(
    id              NUMBER (12, 0) NOT NULL,
    manager_code    VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    employee_code   VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_uk1 UNIQUE (manager_code, employee_code),
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (manager_code) REFERENCES manager (code),
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (employee_code) REFERENCES employee (code)
);

CREATE TABLE project
(
    id     NUMBER (12, 0) NOT NULL,
    code   VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    name   VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT project_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT project_uk1 UNIQUE (code)
);

CREATE TABLE manager_employee_project
(
    id                    NUMBER (12, 0) NOT NULL,
    manager_employee_id   NUMBER (12, 0) NOT NULL,
    project_code          VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_project_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_project_uk1 UNIQUE (manager_employee_id, project_code),
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_project_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (manager_employee_id) REFERENCES manager_employee (id),
    CONSTRAINT manager_employee_project_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (project_code) REFERENCES project (code)
);
```

Building this as a ***Spring Boot (2.1.9)*** application and deploying to ***JBoss 7.0.1 (EAP)*** results in **org.hibernate.MappingException**:

```
16:37:52,208 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 188) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./api/workspace-api: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./api/workspace-api: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property-ref [_my_workspace_persistence_model_test_ManagerEmployee_projects] not found on entity [my.worksace.persistence.model.test.ManagerEmployee]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property-ref [_my_workspace_persistence_model_test_ManagerEmployee_projects] not found on entity [my.workspace.persistence.model.test.ManagerEmployee]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:99)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: property-ref [_my_workspace_persistence_model_test_ManagerEmployee_projects] not found on entity [my.workspace.persistence.model.test.ManagerEmployee]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:192)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:174)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:239)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property-ref [_my_workspace_persistence_model_test_ManagerEmployee_projects] not found on entity [my.workspace.persistence.model.test.ManagerEmployee]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getReferencedProperty(PersistentClass.java:442)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl$DelayedPropertyReferenceHandlerAnnotationImpl.process(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1250)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processPropertyReferences(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1971)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1666)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property [_my_workspace_persistence_model_test_ManagerEmployee_projects] not found on entity [my.workspace.persistence.model.test.ManagerEmployee]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getRecursiveProperty(PersistentClass.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getReferencedProperty(PersistentClass.java:438)
```

Here are the entity definitions:

***Manager.java***

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "manager")
public class Manager {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "manager_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(
      name = "manager_generator",
      sequenceName = "manager_seq",
      allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Code cannot be Null")
  private String code;

  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Recipient Name cannot be Null")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Recipient Name cannot be Null")
  private String lastName;

  @ManyToMany(
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinTable(
      name = "manager_employee",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "manager_code", referencedColumnName = "code")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_code", referencedColumnName = "code")})
  private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

***Employee.java***

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(
      name = "employee_generator",
      sequenceName = "employee_seq",
      allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Code cannot be Null")
  private String code;

  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Recipient Name cannot be Null")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Recipient Name cannot be Null")
  private String lastName;

  @ManyToMany(
      mappedBy = "employees",
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JsonBackReference
  private Set<Manager> Manager = new HashSet<>();
}
```

***Project.java***

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "project_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(
      name = "project_generator",
      sequenceName = "project_seq",
      allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Code cannot be Null")
  private String code;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Recipient Name cannot be Null")
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(
      mappedBy = "projects",
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JsonBackReference
  private Set<ManagerEmployee> managerEmployees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

***ManagerEmployee.java***

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Builder
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "manager_employee")
public class ManagerEmployee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "manager_employee_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(
      name = "manager_employee_generator",
      sequenceName = "manager_employee_seq",
      allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "manager_code", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Sub Group Code cannot be Null")
  private String managerCode;

  @Column(name = "employee_code", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "Group Code cannot be Null")
  private String employeeCode;

  @ManyToMany(
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinTable(
      name = "manager_employee_project",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "manager_employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_code", referencedColumnName = "code")})
  private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
}
```

***ManagerEmployeeProject.java***

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Builder
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "manager_employee_project")
public class ManagerEmployeeProject {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(
      strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
      generator = "manager_employee_project_generator")
  @SequenceGenerator(
      name = "manager_employee_project_generator",
      sequenceName = "manager_employee_project_seq",
      allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "manager_employee_id")
  @NotNull(message = "User Group - Sub User Group Id cannot be Null")
  private Long managerEmployeeId;

  @Column(name = "project_code", nullable = false)
  @NotNull(message = "User Group - Sub User Group Id cannot be Null")
  private String projectCode;
}
```

How do I set this up in Spring Data JPA to avoid the **org.hibernate.MappingException**?